# Trying to make a boolean mask from a list of columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I'm trying to create a boolean mask from a list of columns.

```
print(mydata[evidencenames] == evidences)
```

mydata[evidencenames] gives a pandas dataframe with 3 columns and evidences gives a value for each of those columns in a list. but when i try to run it, it gives me this error:

> Invalid broadcasting comparison [['Female', 47, 78]] with block values

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html). For your query, a dictionary with list values is required:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Female', 57, 78], ['Female', 47, 78], ['Female', 47, 75]],
                  columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])

evidencenames = ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']
searchvalues = ['Female', 47, 78]

d = dict(zip(evidencenames, ([i] for i in searchvalues)))

df_masked = df[df[evidencenames].isin(d).all(1)]

print(df_masked)

     Col1  Col2  Col3
1  Female    47    78
```

Comment: thx for your response, i was wondering if it would also be possible to do this with the help of a for loop?

Comment: @Martijn, A manual `for` loop is not recommended with Pandas. You should perform operations column-wise which is what `pd.DataFrame.isin` is doing here.